# Node.JS Not working on the internet

Tags: porting, node.js, forward-compatibility

i have the basic webserver hello world app for nodejs on windows and it works on localhost. But when i test it from the internet it cannot connect. I set up port forwarding in my netgear router. Am i missing a step here to make my nodejs server visible to the outside world?

Thanks.

```
var http = require('http');
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
  res.end('Hello World\n');
}).listen(1337, "127.0.0.1");
console.log('Server running at http://127.0.0.1:1337/');
```

Comment: It would help if you show us the code you are using.

Comment: It's just the hello world web server on nodejs website.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Make sure you listen on `0.0.0.0` instead of `127.0.0.1`

`127.0.0.1` is a private network visible only to your computer.  `0.0.0.0`listens to all interfaces, including both the private and public (as public as it can be behind a NAT).

Comment: Cool, where did you learn that? Didn't even know 0.0.0.0 was a valid ip.

Comment: Picked it up somewhere in Linuxland, probably editing lighttpd configs by hand or something.  It's been awhile.

Comment: I have the same problem, I did use 0.0.0.0 but still can't access my server outside.

Comment: @xybrek: create a new question, it's probably a router configuration issue though.

Comment: @insta I just created a new nodejs server using Ubuntu which fixed everything. And did iptables

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're binding the server to IP Address `127.0.0.1` which is localhost. If you want to access it elsewhere you'll need to set it to it's internet IP. Check out whatismyip.com and use that IP instead.

Comment: This won't work if he's behind a NAT.  His internal IP address will (likely) be 192.168.x.x, but his public address will be something entirely different.

Comment: what to do if you're behind a NAT?

Answer (score 0):

Just to make sure.

Your code should run like this.

```
var http = require('http');
const port = 1337;
const host = '0.0.0.0';

http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
  res.end('Hello World\n');
}).listen(port, host);
console.log('Server running at http://${host}:${port}');
```