# nginx to pass 8080 without rewrite

Tags: node.js, nginx, url-rewriting

Following is my **/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default**  now i have installed nodejs to run an app on port 8080.

I dont want nginx to redirect any requests to port 80, i want to use **http** instead of **https**

```
server {

listen 443 ssl spdy;
ssl on;
ssl_certificate /ssl.crt;
ssl_certificate_key /ssl.key; 

root /var/www/html;
index index.php index.html index.htm;

location / {
try_files $uri @rewrite;
}
location @rewrite {
rewrite ^ /index.php;
}

location ~ \.php$ {
fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
include fastcgi_params;
fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
}

}

server {
server_name www.xxxx.com xxxx.com;
return 301 https://xxxx.com$request_uri;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To access your nodejs on port 80 (www.xxxx.com or xxxx.com):

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name www.xxxx.com xxxx.com;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
    }
}
```

Comment: No, i want my current nginx running on port 80 and new node app in 8080

Comment: To be clear: You want to access your node app on xxxx.com:8080?

Comment: Yes, keeping the current website on 80 and node on 8080

Comment: You can tell your node app to listen on 0.0.0.0 instead of 127.0.0.1 and you don't need nginx for that part. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7208062/node-js-not-working-on-the-internet/